# Let user create variables (and their data-type) - Django

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I am trying to write a Django app that does the following:
A user sees various articles and then codes variables against these articles.

```
i.e.:
Article is about Egypt.
User assigns: country = Egypt
```

This, so far, is easy.
What I would love to have, though, is that the user can create the variables himself, without me having to hard-code them into models.
How do I best do this?

Should I use the through-relationship on a manytomany-field or are there other, better, ways to do this?
If I use the through-relationship, how can I let the user choose what data-type the variable should be?
Should I put a field for every fieldtype into the through-model and then have the user choose it somehow?

I know, this is more than one question, but if you answer my first question I would be **very** happy!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641008/how-to-store-arbitrary-name-value-key-pairs-in-a-django-model

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by "user" you mean other apps that are based on the app that contains Article.

Use model inheritance:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

```
class Article(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(...)

class CountryArticle(Article):
    country = SomeSuitableModel()
```